# disabling buttons in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

currently i stuck on a wacky problem in my c# blazor app. I fail on the simple task to disable a button, which i did already before.
In Form i have a bunch of bottons

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:5%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <Tooltip Text="do this.">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => commit_job(upgrade_privs))" disabled="@ActionDisabled">
                do this
            </button>
        </Tooltip>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        <Tooltip Text="do that.">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" @onclick="(() => commit_job(downgrade_privs))" disabled="@ActionDisabled">
                do that
            </button>
        </Tooltip>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The buttons call the same Task, just using different arguments. ActionDisabled is defined as boolean.

```
bool ActionDisabled { get; set; } = false;
```

This is the Task the buttons are calling. At First i set ActionDisabled to True, so all buttons use this boolean for disabled Property should be disabled. Next the Task is doing some stuff, calling other tasks and end the end i set ActionDisabled  back to false.

```
private async Task commit_job(string upordown){
    ActionDisabled = true;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    ActionDisabled = false;
}
```

For my suprise the button is not disabled during task run, strange riddle.
If i comment out the lower "ActionDisabled = false;" I can see that my buttons are disabled. But it seems that it happens on the end of the task and not its beginning.
What did i do wrong? Currently i have no explanation for this behaviour.

Thank You,
Hans

Comment: Add  `await Task.Yield();` after the first state change.

Comment: The code you have provided so far is not enough to reproduce the problem you are describing. I created a demo based on your code and you can see that everything is working correctly: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/we47imx1

Comment: Thanks, the "await Task.Yield();" did the job. it forced the disabling of the buttons directly after state change and delivered my expected behaviour.

Comment: This seems to be true. i changed a Thread.Sleep() into await Task.Delay() and it worked without await Task.Yield()
Thank You.